# dynamically add jquery ajax options

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some couchdb queries, for which I'm using the jquery-couchdb plugin.  I'd like to compile a set of queries with which I can decide at call-time what options to set.  E.g.

```
$db.view("design/view", {
    success: function(data) {
        // do something e.g.:
        callback_function(data);
        },
    option1: value1,
    option2: value2
    // What if I want an option3 to be set only some of the time?
});
```

Is there a way to achieve this?  Something like running over kwargs in python, or a way to pass in an object with keys and values?

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
var params = {};
params.success = function(data) {
    // do something e.g.:
    callback_function(data);
    };
if (setOpt1) params.option1 = value1;
if (setOpt2) params.option2 = value2;
$db.view("design/view", params);
```

Comment: Yup, that's done it!  Examples always seem to show specific queries, it looks to me that using something based on this would improve brevity!